# Why don't I get the json string /command object back when using jQuery ajax post method?

Tags: json, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am using **Spring 2.5.5, jQuery 1.4.4, spring-json1.3.1** (and the optional sojo-optional-0.5.0.jar - it says *optional*, but I needed this cause it threw some ClassNotFound exception regarding sojo - but this is not the issue :) ).

**I am interested why when using** ***POST in contrast to GET*** with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "sizesOrColors.json",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",//"GET",
      data: "productId=1&sizeOrColorId=111&isSize=true",
      dataType: "json",//html",
      async:false,
      success: function(javascriptObjectFromJsonFile){
      var colorsOrSizesMap = javascriptObjectFromJsonFile.command.colorsOrSizesMap;
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      //some error handling code...
      }
   }
);
```

**the javascriptObjectFromJsonFile doesn't have the "command" property?** When using the GET method, I receive the "command" property.
When accessing the success callback function, with the POST method, the console throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'colorsOrSizesMap' of
>   undefined

*Remember*: If specifying dataType: "json", jQuery converts the json string to a javascript Object:[Handling the JSON data type](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests). (Previously I tried with parseJSON but now I know that's not appropriate).
**Example of the json string I receive with the GET method is**:

```
{"command":{"colorsOrSizesMap":{"123":"Blue","128":"White"},"errorsFromGet":[]}}
```

Now, I suspect there is something to do with the way the Spring's SimpleFormController.onSubmit method handles the POST method (as described by [spring-json1.3.1](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/quick_simpleform.html))

> Even the type converting of
>   CommandBean-Properties is supported.
>   The GET request is hitting the
>   formBackingObject method.
>   The POST
>   request is hitting the onSubmitAction
>   method.

Although here spring-json team says the POST request is hitting the onSubmitAction method, I never got it to go there. And the processing path goes through the formBackingObject also. **The correct path** the Controller took was:
-**formBackingObject**(HttpServletRequest request)
-**initBinder**(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception
-Validator.**validate**(...) method
-**onSubmit**(Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception
(**not onSubmitAction**)
This is regardless using sessionForm true or false (in the servlet configuration when configuring the SimpleFormController json bean).
**There is no problem when I receive the command object in the onSubmit method - it is populated with all the parameters from the data string ("productId=1&sizeOrColorId=111&isSize=true"). But when the method returns the ModelAndView, something happens either on Spring side (but there is no exception or error), or on the client side when jQuery tries to convert the json string to javascript object. Probably, since I don't get the "command" property in the javascript object with the POST method (and get it with the GET method), there is some problem on the server side. But what?**

If you can't get the solution from the case I presented above, I would be glad to post some additional code on your demand.

Any help would be appreciated. Particularly form someone that already implemented the spring-json library.

Kind Regards,
Despot
P.S.: As you can see, I avoided using the prototype.js library (evalJSON() method and Ajax object both are part of prototype - see the [JavaScript behaviour-roles.js](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/quick_simpleform.html))

EDIT: This is how the javascriptObjectFromJsonFile object looks like (in the image the javascriptObjectFromJsonFile is msg):
[image: http://img824.imageshack.us/i/jsstatuswhensuccessfrom.jpg/]

Comment: `SimpleFormController` is not appropriate for AJAX-style requests. What made you choose that?

Comment: @skaffman - see http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/quick_simpleform.html (look for the "Controller Source" header). From the three options offered by spring-json documentation this was the most convenient since it provides validating and POST capabilities (see the explanation in the documentation for more to understand what I mean). Anyways, what would you propose?

Comment: Since Spring 3, Spring JSON is unnecessary and over-complicated. Spring now provides its own JSON support, and uses the much simpler annotated controller style.

Comment: @skaffman - I know that Spring 3 uses it's own JSON library to handle things, but I am using Spring 2.5.5. If you have read a tutorial or have a piece of info how I could do that for Spring 2.5.5, please do share it with me. As for the annotated style - it is a preference. I don't have to use annotations. You can just as easily configure beans without annotations. Back to the question, what type of controller do you think is suitable for AJAX-style requests and why? I think we are going off topic here, but more info is useful either way.